# Replacing one div with another using input button

Tags: jquery

I am using the example from stack. IS there a way to to use submit button to hide a div and show another div .
I tried with an image and it works. basically I have a registration form. I want the div to fade and the hidden div to show on submit.obviously after php critiria are met

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both `div`s in the markup, you can use `.show(time,callback_function)` to show the hidden element or `.hide(time,callback_function)`to hide the hidden element with animation. "time" is the animation duration in ms, "callback_function" is an arbitrary function which can be called at the end of the animation. You can hide the hidden element by CSS `display:none`.

If the hidden element does not exist in the original HTML markup, you need to create it and append it to the parent `div`. You can check out `add_file()` function in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/qz6f6zhv/) to see how you can create new HTML markup using jQuery on-the-go and add it to your existing markup.

Comment: <script>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#img1").on('click', function() {
 
   $("#div1").fadeOut();
   $("#div2").fadeIn();
   
});

$("#img2").on('click', function() {
   $("#div1").fadeIn();
   $("#div2").fadeOut();
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img id="img1"/> <img id="img2"/> <br/>
<div id="div1">register</div>
<div id="div2">thank you</div>
<form>
<input type="submit" id="img1" value="SUBMIT"

Comment: @shabs: Glad it worked. Please accept the answer using up arrow.